# Spacing between label and sectiontitle

Tags: latex, overleaf

I would like to change the spacing between the label and the section title. Right now I'm using `titlesec` with `scrartcl`, but there are warnings. I guess it is because `titlesec` has some problems with KOMA-script.

So I would like to create the same by using KOMA-Script commands. Do you have an idea?

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1cm}{}


\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{3cm}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{5cm}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Ein erster Abschnitt}
\subsection{Unterabschnitt}
\subsubsection{Unter-Unterabschnitt}

\end{document}
```

[Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h1i2.jpg)

[Output document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Li4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass[
%pdftex,
a4paper]{scrartcl}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection\autodot\enskip\hspace{2cm}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\thesubsection\autodot\enskip\hspace{2cm}} 
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip\hspace{2cm}}

\begin{document}

\section{Ein erster Abschnitt}
\subsection{Unterabschnitt}
\subsubsection{Unter-Unterabschnitt}

\end{document}
```